# cakephp notice 8: undefined index:

Tags: cakephp

I am getting the cakephp notice 8 on my view.ctp page for Category, Product and Size.

Here is my ProductsController for view:

```
public function view($id) {
    $result = $this->Product->find('all', array(
        'contain' => array(
            'Category' => array(
                'Size'
            )

        ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'Product.id' => $id
        )

    ));

     $this->set(compact(
        'result'
    ));
```

Here is the view.ctp:

```
<?php

$product = $result['Product'];
$category = $result['Category'];
$sizes = $category['Size'];

pr($result);

echo "<h2>" . $product['name'] . "</h2>";
echo "<div>". $product['description'] . "</div>";

echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('sizes');


echo "<h3>" . $size['name'] . "</h3>";

//echo $this->Html->link('Add to Paypal cart', $paypalUrl);

echo '<br />';
echo '<br />';

echo '<h3>Add to cart</h3>';

echo $this->Form->create(false); //  FALSE FOR NO MODEL
echo $this->Form->input('quantity');
echo $this->Form->submit('Add to cart');
echo $this->Form->end();


?>
```

I did a `pr($result);` and the Array showed all the information that I need:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Product] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 115
                    [name] => Curly Indian Fusions Extensions
                    [description] => Small groups of luxurious 100% virgin human hair strands are matched to coloured high-quality keratin tips
                    [image] => ../webroot/img/hciImages/curlyVirginUtipSMA.jpg
                    [category_id] => 10
                    [created] => 0000-00-00
                    [modified] => 0000-00-00
                )

            [Category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [name] => Indian Fusion Extensions
                    [desc] => Small groups of luxurious 100% virgin human hair strands are attached to matched colour high quality keratin tips.
                    [Size] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 225
                                    [name] => 12 inches
                                    [category_id] => 10
                                    [price] => 2.50
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 226
                                    [name] => 14 inches
                                    [category_id] => 10
                                    [price] => 2.50
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 227
                                    [name] => 16 inches
                                    [category_id] => 10
                                    [price] => 2.50
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 228
                                    [name] => 18 inches
                                    [category_id] => 10
                                    [price] => 3.00
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 229
                                    [name] => 20 inches
                                    [category_id] => 10
                                    [price] => 3.50
                                )

                            [5] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 230
                                    [name] => 22 inches
                                    [category_id] => 10
                                    [price] => 3.50
                                )

                            [6] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 231
                                    [name] => 24 inches
                                    [category_id] => 10
                                    [price] => 4.50
                                )

                            [7] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 232
                                    [name] => 26 inches
                                    [category_id] => 10
                                    [price] => 4.60
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

So all the information is there, but not displaying. I have a feeling I've not called the information properly but can't figure why the information is not defined if it is there. Any guidance is appreciated, I'm a noob.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe this typo: echo `"<h3>" . $size['name'] . "</h3>";` because you created a $sizes array

Comment: You didnt specify version of Cake you are using. But, if 2.x, you could use `first` instead of `all`. Like `$result = $this->Product->find('first', array(`. Your view will then work... as is

Comment: Thank you! Using 'first' helped! Now the sizes aren't displaying but as AgRizzo pointed out I'll need to make a select dropdown, which I read about in the formHelper section of the documentation. I'm going to go and play with that. Thank you again for all of your help friends!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `loop` for represent data of `$result`. in this case just replace

```
$product = $result[0]['Product'];
$category = $result[0]['Category'];
$sizes = $category['Size'];
```

instead

```
$product = $result['Product'];
$category = $result['Category'];
$sizes = $category['Size']
```

**Update** :

```
foreach($sizes as $size)  {
   echo "<h3>" . $size['name'] . "</h3>";
}
```